# Exclude file from compile configuration

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to setup the configuration from my project.  I currently use my project to connect to different ip addresses.  I would like to include the ip address that is in a seperate file for different builds.

I have .cs files and when I select the properties, the property window appears however I do not have access to the property page to exclude the file from the particular deployment.

Any addvise?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the source file (.cs) in the Solution Explorer, there's an option called "Build Action" in the property window. Change that from "Compile" to "None", and the compiler won't include it when you build the project.